# Simple routing not working

Tags: routing, routeros

I have a problem with my virtual environment. On this picture you can see my configuration:

[image: configuration]

I have a total of three subnets. Where one router with 192.168.1.1 is physical and one virtual router and two virtual machines.

all virtual devices are configured with the virtual bridge vmbr0.

which works:

192.168.10.100 can ping 192.168.1.180

192.168.12.10 can ping 192.168.1.180

192.168.1.180 can ping 192.168.1.1

so basically the connections are there but for some reason i can't ping the physical router from the virtual machines although the virtual router sees the physical one.

do you see an error? here are some printscreens of my configurations

The Interfaces
[image: The Interfaces]
<sub>(source: [amplus.ch](https://amplus.ch/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Router-Interfaces.png))</sub>

Route List
[image: Route List]
<sub>(source: [amplus.ch](https://amplus.ch/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Routes.png))</sub>

Bridge Konfiguration(ino4 is the physical interface
[image: Birdge Konfiguration(ino4 is the physical interface]
<sub>(source: [amplus.ch](https://amplus.ch/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/bridge.png))</sub>

Comment: Do this VMs have default route pointed to router?

Comment: unfortunately yes
[link](https://amplus.ch/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/ipconfig.png)

Comment: and from 192.168.10.100 i can ping to 192.168.12.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now changed the whole thing to PF Sense and it works perfectly and without any problems. The thread can be closed

Comment: Hi, please accept your answer when you will be able and it would be closed afterhand. Thanks !